# JSF redirect with duplicated FacesServlet prefix

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, navigation, cdi

When redirecting to another page, the browser address bar shows "/faces/faces". Why is it happening?

I'm getting a strange warning from JSF:

WARNING: JSF1015: Request path '/faces/pages/unity/view.xhtml' begins with one or more occurrences of the FacesServlet prefix path mapping '/faces'.

The navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/unity/list.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>VIEW</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/unity/view.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The commandButton on list.xhtml:

```
     <h:commandButton value="View" action="#{unityController.view(item)}" />
```

I've also tried implicit navigation but the result is the same.

unityController is a conversation scoped cdi bean.

Comment: can you post your `URL` mapping in web.xml?

Comment: @SRy
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>